# How can I set the adUnitId programmatically?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

How can I add an adUnitId (Admob) to my android app (eclipse) programmatically?
I will receive this ID over the network!

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
```

> *fictional:* request.SETadUnitId("ADUNITID");

```
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Comment: @Mukesh I can't use the xml style if I use your code... Is there no other way?

Comment: @Mukesh: Do not add a solution to the OP's post. You have the provision to provide your own answer. The OP can choose to add the solution to his / her own questions but you shouldn't!

Comment: User @Mukesh comment moved here: `AdView adView = new AdView(activity, adSize, adUnitId);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I deleted the XML style and defined an `AdView` programmatically.

```
`AdView adView = new AdView(activity, adSize, "MY_AD_UNIT_ID")`;
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is outdated . This contractor is no longer exist . You should use:

```
AdView mAdViewTemp = new AdView(this);
mAdViewTemp.setAdUnitId(bannerUnit);
mAdViewTemp.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
```